# Redux update state only after a full page reload

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form that is per-populated based on user saved information and the user can change those information at any time.

A simple example of how this is structured is:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const { user, getProfile } = this.props;

    if (user.profileId) {
      getProfile(user.profileId); // this is a redux action that fetch for user profile data updating the props.
    }
  }



  onChangeValue(e) {
    const { updateProfileField } = this.props; // this is a redux action to update a single input
    const { id, value } = e.target;

    updateProfileField(id, value);
  }
```

Inputs looks like this:

```
<InputField id="screenName" type="text" value={profile.screenName} onChangeValue={this.onChangeValue} placeholder="Your username" />
```

The `InputField` component is the following:

```
class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: props.value,
    };

    this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeValue(value) {
    this.props.onChangeValue(value);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      id, type, parent,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <input
        id={id}
        parent-id={parent}
        className="form-control"
        type={type}
        name={id}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The Redux action to handle the `updateProfileField` is:

```
export function updateProfileField(field, value) {
  const payload = { field, value };
  return dispatch => dispatch({payload, type: types.UPDATE_PROFILE_FIELD});
}
```

Finally the Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  data: {}, // Here are stored the profile information like `screenName`
  ...
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    ...
    case types.UPDATE_PROFILE_FIELD:

      // Here my attempts to update the input value

      return {
        ...state,
        data: { ...state.data, [payload.field]: payload.value },
      };

      // Immutability helper
      // return update(state, {
      //   data: { [payload.field]: { $set: payload.value } },
      // });

      // return Object.assign({}, state.data, {
      //   [payload.field]: payload.value,
      // });
  }
}
```

The point is that everything works just fine as soon as I load the page and I start to type the information in my form.

If I change something in the code, it reload automatically using `HMR`, I can see the information typed before in the inputs but if I try to update the information it doesn't work anymore...

I can see the `"state"` updating just the last letter of the input and the UI seems freeze. (ie.: input value is: 'foo', I type: 'bar' the result is: foob, fooa, foor... and it is not reflected in the UI).

I think I'm doing something wrong in here...

Comment: you have to bind the function in ur parent component when u use   < InputField /> this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);

Comment: It is done in the constructor.

Comment: Could that be just related to HMR issue, so not a problem for live app?